# Blender 3.1 Edit Mode Cursor Changed From Arrow to Crosshair

Tags: interface

Hitting hotkeys while I was modeling and the regular cursor (not 3D cursor) suddenly
changed into a crosshair from the arrow it was before. I just wanna change it back. I can't
find any info on how to change the cursor shape. I tried changing the "precision select" cursor from a crosshair to an arrow in the Windows 11 settings but that didn't solve the
problem. I have seen this question asked before but never satisfactorily answered.

Comment: It's always been a crosshair in Edit mode from Blender 2.8.3 right through to 3.4 here. (Just checked back through the versions I have installed here.)

Comment: As @JohnEason says... I still have a 2.79 version here, and it has been a crosshair back then, too. From which version did you come to 3.1 that the crosshair is something new to you? Be prepared, a lot more than just the cursor changed since Blender's childhood ;)